# Changing <p:tree> height

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using  and I have a long list of nodes.

I can change the width size but not the height
How can I change the tree height ?

```
.ui-tree-container {
   border:1px solid;
   width: 20%;
   height: 20%;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some context/links?

Comment: I have more than 3000 nodes and want to use a scroller instead of expending the node list all over the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working

```
.ui-tree {
  height: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a real number like 20px, not percentages for height.

Comment: try adding the rule display: block; and or position: relative;